# A problem about general topology. (homeomorphims)

Tags: general-topology

Let $f:X \to Y$ homeomorphims and $A \subseteq X$ have the property that $A \cap A^{'}=\emptyset$. Then $f(A)\cap (f(A))^{'}=\emptyset$.

Idea: Contrapositive.

Suposse $f(A)\cap (f(A))^{'} \neq \emptyset$. Let $y \in f(A)\cap (f(A))^{'}$ and $x$ such that $f(x)=y$.

Then, for every neighborhood $V$ of $y$: $f(A) \cap (V \backslash \{y \}) \neq \emptyset$.

Comment: I'd do it in a different way: Since $f$ is a homeomorphism, it preserves every topological concept, in particular $f(A')=f(A)'$, hence
$$f(A)\cap f(A)' = f(A)\cap f(A') = f(A\cap A') = f(\emptyset) = \emptyset$$

Comment: thank's !!. but, $f(A')=f(A)^{'}$ ?, if $f$ is a homeo.

Comment: Yes, $f(b)\in f(A)'\iff \text{every neighborhood $f(U)$ of $f(b)$ contains some $f(a)\ne f(b)$ for $a\in A$} \iff \text{ every neighborhood $U$ of $b$ contains some $a\ne b$ in $A$} \iff b\in A' \iff f(b)\in f(A')$